# Candlestick views are generated but not displayed

Tags: ios, swiftcharts

Using the [SwiftCharts](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts) library, I have a chart of candlesticks. And they are generated and I can track them. But some on the far right are not visible on the screen / seem to be behind some other views of the chart?

[image]

You can, however, see them here in the view debugger which confirms they exist (on the far right):
[image]

How can I make sure all candlestick views are displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it turned out the container view of the chart view was clipping bounds. This one liner right before adding the chart.view as a subview fixed it:

```
chart.containerView.clipsToBounds = false
```